# iText rotate() won't orient the first page

Tags: java, itext

Everything I have read regarding iText says you should be able to set the page size and then create a new page. But for some reason when I try this my first page isn't rotated. But my second is. Any ideas?

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
Document document = new Document();

try{
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer); 
    document.open();
    //Start a new page
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate()); //  11" x 8.5"  new Rectangle(792f, 612f)

    document.newPage();
    Paragraph topText = new Paragraph();
    // add some content here...
    document.close(); 

    DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        dataOutput.writeByte(bytes[i]);
    }

} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try setting the page size *before* calling `document.open()`. IIRC, `document.newPage()` really means "finish the current page and then start a new one", i.e. a document is opened with one blank page ready for use.

Comment: If it worked, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Also: why are you writing out the PDF byte-by-byte using `DataOutputStream`? If it's generated on the fly, you might as well write it out directly to the HTTP response output stream; or if you really want the content length to be advertised, just write out the byte array with [`OutputStream.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[]))

Comment: I'll be honest. I don't know what I am doing. I am just copying and pasting code from the internet. What would be the syntax to write it out directly?

Comment: Instead of what you have now, use `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());` and get rid of the DataOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: millimoose, you are too sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.newPage()` really means "finish the current page and open a new one". This implies that after you `open()` a document, you already have a blank page (with whatever size the document had set before) ready.

You should set your page size before opening the document:

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
document.open();
```